# Number of permutations in which a integer appears before other

Tags: combinatorics

Two integers $x$, and $y$ are fixed such that $1 \le x < y \le n$.
I am trying to count the number of permutations of {$1,2,3,4,...,n$}
($n \ge 2$) were $x$ appears to the left of $y$.

I think I should use product rule in this case but I am not sure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Hint:**

To answer how many of these will have $x$ to the left of $y$,

think about how many of these will have $x$ to the *right* of $y$.

Are these numbers related?

> There are exactly as many permutations with $x$ to the left of $y$ as there are having $x$ to the right of $y$.  See if you can explain why using a bijective function between them.

What does this imply about the total number of permutations in relation to the number of permutations with $x$ to the left of $y$?

---

For a direct counting argument instead of a combinatorial argument, first pick which two spaces the pair $x,y$ will occupy.  Whichever two spaces you picked, put $x$ in the left space and $y$ in the right.  From there, fill in the remaining spaces however you prefer (left to right or smallest to largest, etc...).

> There are then $\binom{n}{2}$ ways of picking which two spaces $x$ and $y$ collectively occupy and $(n-2)!$ number of ways of picking the arrangement of the remaining numbers.  Apply multiplication rule.

Comment: Is this one of those situations were I consider "all permutations in the universe" - "permutations were $y$ appears to the left of $x$"

Comment: @samantha you certainly could, and that is the answer I was hinting at in the first half.  It will all simplify very nicely.

Comment: Ok thanks. And also the total amount of permutations is $9^n$ right?

Comment: @samantha Where did you get the number $9$ from?  The number of permutations of the set $\{1,2,3,\dots,n\}$ is $n!$.

Answer (score -1):

Take the position of $y$ and make this partition of the set:

$$\{1,2,...,n\}=\{1,...,i\}\cup\{y\}\cup\{j,...,n\}$$

Now count when $x \in\{1,...,i\}$.

This is the canonical way to solve this kind of permutations, how it appear in textbooks (by example *Bijective combinatorics* if I remember correctly).

It works for a lot of words with order restrictions. In this case it is very easy cause there is only one restriction, i.e. $x<y$ and the answer is "trivialy" $n!/2$ (just by symmetry).